# Checking last sender of a thread and update status

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, where-clause, window-functions

I have two tables

**message**

```
id ,thread_id ,sender_id ,message_content
1.   10.         2.          message_content_1
2.    5.          1          message_content_2
```

**thread**

```
id status
5.  close
10. Open
```

What I am trying to achieve is if the latest send_id!=1(aka not admin) > I want to update the thread status to open .

What I did so far

```
UPDATE thread
SET thread.status=open
RIGHT JOIN message
ON thread.id=message.thread_id 
WHERE message.senderId!=1 AND (SELECT max(message.id) FROM message WHERE message.thread_id=thread.id)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: probably latest , I can't view much via phpmyadmin . this is what I found Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to get for each `thread_id` the last `sender_id`:

```
UPDATE thread t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT thread_id, 
         FIRST_VALUE(sender_id) OVER (PARTITION BY thread_id ORDER BY id DESC) sender_id
  FROM message
) m ON m.thread_id = t.id
SET t.status = 'open'
WHERE m.sender_id <> 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9120a57a9c036ae5d2ee493b8682caae).

Comment: let me check sir

Comment: Work flawlessly. thanks

Answer (score 1):

i hope this would work.

```
update thread join message on thread.id=message.thread_id set thread.status='open' where message.sender_id!=1 and (SELECT max(message.id) FROM message);
```

Comment: let me check sir

Comment: I tried and all thread become open :D. I only want to change thread.status to open where last message sender is non-admin (which is message.sender_id!=1) . But yours give me a head start and I will continue to work

Comment: update thread join message on thread.id=message.thread_id set thread.state='open' where message.sender_id!=1 and (SELECT max(message.id) FROM message GROUP BY message.thread_id); this is what I came up with triggering (Subquery returns more than 1 row) error